# Data frame to matrix without using reshape

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame:

```
set.seed(1234)
mydata <- data.frame(d1=strsplit("AAABBCCCCCDD", "")[[1]],
d2=rnorm(12), d3=c("aba", "bbc", "ccb", "aba", "bbc", "ccb", "aba", "aba", "ccb", "bbc", "aba", "bbc"),
d4=c(101:103, 201:202, 301:305, 401:402))
```

and I want a matrix of d1 by d3 containing the sum of each d3 in each d1.

I could use the package reshape, but the problem is that I'm using R 3.0, and there is no version of reshape for it.

Any suggestion?
Cheers!

Comment: Which thing are you summing? d2 and d4 are both numeric...

Comment: Could you use the `reshape2` package that replaced `reshape`?

Comment: Um, reshape works fine in R 3.0.0

Answer (score 2):

First, reshape (and reshape2) work fine with R 3.0. Second, I assume you're summing d2, instead of d3. You can use `plyr` for this.

```
require(plyr)
ddply(mydata, .(d1), summarise, d2=sum(d2))
```

Comment: yes, sorry! I'm summing d2!I guess I'm having some problems with my R version!

Answer (score 2):

This does it, for whichever variable you want. Just switch d2 to d4.

```
tapply(mydata$d2,mydata[,c("d1","d3")],sum)
```

The result is...

```
   d3
d1         aba        bbc         ccb
  A -1.2070657  0.2774292  1.08444118
  B -2.3456977  0.4291247          NA
  C -1.1213718 -0.8900378 -0.05839611
  D -0.4771927 -0.9983864          NA
```

Comment: Your answers and @Ananda did work! But this is nether a matrix nor a data frame! If I try as.data.frame it goes back to the former condition!

Comment: I'm seeing `is.matrix(tapply(mydata$d2,mydata[,c("d1","d3")],sum))` come up as `TRUE` (and the same for Ananda Mahto's solution). Maybe you mean something else by "matrix" than the standard R meaning...?

Comment: @user2335669, if I use `as.data.frame` on Frank's answer, I get a `data.frame`. To get a `data.frame` from my answer, you have to use `as.data.frame.matrix` instead of `as.data.frame`.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, your question is not clear. If you're only interested in `sum` as the aggregation function, then you can simply use `xtabs`:

```
> xtabs(d2 ~ d1 + d3, mydata)
   d3
d1          aba         bbc         ccb
  A -1.20706575  0.27742924  1.08444118
  B -2.34569770  0.42912469  0.00000000
  C -1.12137182 -0.89003783 -0.05839611
  D -0.47719270 -0.99838644  0.00000000
```

To get back to a `data.frame`, wrap the entire thing in `as.data.frame.matrix` (not just `as.data.frame`):

```
> as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(d2 ~ d1 + d3, mydata))
         aba        bbc         ccb
A -1.2070657  0.2774292  1.08444118
B -2.3456977  0.4291247  0.00000000
C -1.1213718 -0.8900378 -0.05839611
D -0.4771927 -0.9983864  0.00000000
```